# best practice to develop a custom android application with share core

Tags: android

i'll try to better explain my question.
We are are developing a business application for a target customer.
This application has some function very specific for the customer but the core should be re-used for other customer.
For istance the log-in activity would be the same for all customers, but customer A could see activity A and customer B could see activity B and so on...what part of the app to show is managed from the data returned by log in.

I'd like to have only ona project in order to better mantain it....but here my question:
i create the application for customer A, with common activities and custom activities.
I put this application with package name com.mybigapplication and with apk name mybigapplication.apk in the play store.

Customer A download install and use it.

Now I have customer B, I take the same project, I'll add the custom activities for customer B and I'd like to put the app in the play store.

Here my problem if i put the app with same package and apk name the customer A will update the app without any reason...

How can I do ?
Is there a way to manage this problems ?

Please notice that I haven't already put anything in the store.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go is putting the common code in an Android Library project, that the specialized apps for customer A and customer B will depend on. So you will have 3 projects in Eclipse:

- common (Library)
- customerA (Android)
- customerB (Android)

An Android application is uniquely identified by the `package` attribute in `AndroidManifest.xml`. The two android projects can (actually must) have different `package` attribute in their manifest, that's how upgrading one app will not affect the other.

For more details on library projects, see the docs:
http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects

This article may also be helpful:
http://blog.donnfelker.com/2010/08/05/howto-android-full-and-lite-versions/

Comment: The library project seems the right solutions for me, thanks for help. I'll give a try.

Answer (score 0):

A trivial solution would be to create 2 separate projects with different package names.

Then write a shell script or something that just periodically copies all the source files from the directory of project A to project B.

You have to be careful not to copy stuff that might mess up configurations etc. You'll have to manually adjust those. for example, the manifest file can't be copied directly; You'll have to manually add any activities, Services etc in Project A to Project B's manifest too.

Another option is to create an [Android library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects) with the shared code and just include it in both the projects. [Here's a tutorial on this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html).